# How do I convert the returned maps to json csv in HugSQL results

Tags: clojure, hugsql

I am trying to use HugSQL to select some records from my DB and I get back the records
I have few problems when I try this code:

```
f/attempt-all [_ (println  "Getting DB records")
                    db-records (oracle-db/get-records my-db)
;hangs here when there are large(100,000k+) records
```

and

```
-- :name get-records
select /*+ index(src_ski_sysevents_au SRC_SKI_SYSEVENTS_AU_IDX_A)*/ * from src_ski_sysevents_au where week_id='201903' AND ROWNUM <'10000'
```

Actual results: 
db-records has a list of maps(map for each record returned) like this:

```
({:remarks nil, :timeprocessing 1994-01-01 00:00:00.000, :devicetype 3M, :staffcode 0M, 
           :timedeletion 1994-01-01 00:00:00.000, :occurred 1M, :syseventdesig Ticket jam, :time 2019-01-14 10:47:37.350, :syseventno 27M, 
  :devicedesig P4 LH Exit Wilga ST - 49, :devicenoprocessing 0M, :component nil, :lotabbr P3P4, :deviceabbr P4 LEX WIL, 
  :week_id 201903M, :lotdesig P3, P4 Levels, :dss_update_time #inst "2019-01-14T15:48:46.000000000-00:00", :loaded_new_yn N, 
  :operatorfirstname nil, :quantity 1M, :systemeventregno 7365M, :pdi_batch_id 697410M, :lotno 1M, :deviceno 49M, :deleted_yn N, 
  :centre_no 0012000, :lot_no 0012001, :operatorsurname unattended, :operatornoprocessing 0M}
  ...
)
```

I want to know how to convert this list of maps to a Json string file or CSV file to push it to my endpoint. While handling non-string values like

:timeprocessing 1994-01-01 00:00:00.000

I see errors for these as soon as I put this test string in to test in a  `(comment (def testmap {input_test_Data}))` with invalid number format and I also found that

:dss_update_time in my DB is "15/JAN/19"

but in the HugSQL results I get something like this

:dss_update_time #inst "2019-01-14T15:48:46.000000000-00:00"

Basically how would I ensure I get back all the data 
Would really appreciate some help on the second part of my problem at least. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please use the function `prn` instead of `println` to print out a sample data row. Then you will see that the date values are actually strings (`prn` will not strip away the double-quote chars like `println` does).

At that point, you can just use normal EDN->JSON conversion.  There is [a simple function](https://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.core.html#var-edn-.3Ejson) in [the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo):

```
(t/edn->json  {:a 1  :b 2})
;=> {"a":1,"b":2}
```

which just uses the Cheshire lib under the covers and automatically does keyword<->string conversion.

Comment: Thank you Alan Thompson I ll check that and get back.